# Process custom xml elements in xml document code comments for MSDN style Help files

Tags: sandcastle, xml-documentation, xml-comments, ghostdoc, help-files

I am looking for a way to build Help files that include custom XML elements for a large project. I want to add my own element similar to the Summary element and have the help files include it. I have Sandcastle and Ghost Doc Pro installed. I have not been able to find a way to have either of these help file builders include my custom tag. An example:

```
    /// <summary>
    ///     the summary
    /// </summary>
    /// <customElement>
    ///     My custom element contents
    /// </customElement>
```

If anyone can turn me onto a lead of where I might find the documentation to have the custom element included in the documentation, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In both Sandcastle and GhostDoc you'd have to create custom theme with your custom transformations that know how to handle your own tags. They won't pick up custom tags out of the box.

Thanks!